# How to Convert number to word using SQL Query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need help to converting amount (number) to words using SQL Query.

Example: Rs. 287.06 -> TWO HUNDRED EIGHTY-SEVEN AND 06/100 RUPEES

Requesting you to suggest how can I achieve it.

Regards,

Ashok

Comment: You should tag your questions with the database you are really using.  Given that the Oracle tags are more specific and abundant, I removed "mysql".

Answer (score 0):

This is not my solution, I have founded this function here:

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1407603857650

Here is one more article:
https://www.foxinfotech.in/2019/04/oracle-convert-currency-amount-in-words-using-pl-sql.html

That has almost exactly what you need.
Both of the solutions are tested in my demo at the end...

```
create or replace
 function spell_number( p_number in number )
 return varchar2
 as
 type myArray is table of varchar2(255);
 l_str myArray := myArray( '',
 ' thousand ', ' million ',
 ' billion ', ' trillion ',
 ' quadrillion ', ' quintillion ',
 ' sextillion ', ' septillion ',
 ' octillion ', ' nonillion ',
 ' decillion ', ' undecillion ',
 ' duodecillion ' );

 l_num varchar2(50) default trunc( p_number );
 l_return varchar2(4000);
 begin
 for i in 1 .. l_str.count
 loop
 exit when l_num is null;

 if ( substr(l_num, length(l_num)-2, 3) <> 0 )
 then
 l_return := to_char(
 to_date(
 substr(l_num, length(l_num)-2, 3),
 'J' ),
 'Jsp' ) || l_str(i) || l_return;
 end if;
 l_num := substr( l_num, 1, length(l_num)-3 );
 end loop;

 return l_return;
end;
/
```

Sadly for your example it will not do the job because of the `.` but I am sure you can combine few soultions where you split the number if it has a decimal part and then call this function for the number and some other for the decimal parts...

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6dcd92db2250e40f5dcac833ce591559)

Comment: I assume it is -1 because I have shared someone else's solution ..